# Parallel execution 'mvn test' in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I try to create jenkinsfile for parallel execution command mvn test with different arguments. On the first stage of jenkinsfile I create *.csv file where are will be future arguments for mvn test command. Also I don't know the quantity of parallel stages (it depends on first stage where I get data from DB). So, summarize it again. Logic:

1. First stage for getting data from DB over command mvn test (with args). On this test I save data into csv file.
2. In loop of jenkinsfile I read every string, parse it and get args for arallel execution mvn test (with args based on the parsed data).

Now it looks like this (only necessary fragments of jenkinsfile):

```
def buildProject = { a, b, c ->
    node {
        stage(a) {
            catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                sh "mvn -Dtest=test2 test -Darg1=${b} -Darg2=${c}"
            }
        }
    }
}

stages {
        stage('Preparation of file.csv') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -Dtest=test1 test'
            }
        }
        stage('Parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                   file = readFile "file.csv"
                   lines = file.readLines()

                   def branches = [:]

                   for(i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                       values = lines[i].split(';')
                       branches["${values[0]}"] = { buildProject(values[0], values[1], values[2]) }
                   }
                   
                   parallel branches
                }
           }
       }
}
```

So, which problems do I face now with?

1. I see in log following error:
   [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Data/jenkins/workspace/***/***@2)

I look at workspaces of Jenkins and see that there were created several empty(!!!) directories (quantity equals to quantity of parallel stages). And therefore mvn command could be executed because of absence of pom.xml and other files.

2. In branches the same data are saved on every iteration of loop and in 'stage(a)' I see the same title (but every iteration of loop has unique 'values[0]').

Can you help me with this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have achievement here. I made following changes:

`file = readFile "file.csv"
lines = file.readLines()

def branches = [:]
lines.each { l ->
  branches[l] = {
     values = l.split(';')
     stage(values[0] + " (" + values[1] + ")") {
        sh "mvn -Dtest=Test2 test -Darg1=${values[1]} -Darg2=${values[2]}"
     }
  }
}
parallel branches`

In Jenkins log I see the same mvn command on every stage.
Where is my error?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So, regarding this jenkins issue https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-50307 and workaround which could be found there, task could be closed!

Answer (score 0):

So, regarding this jenkins issue issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-50307 and workaround which could be found there, task could be closed!